# static file with mod_wsgi in django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've searched a lot but I still have a problem with the static files (css, image,...) with my django website.

I'm using mod_wsgi with apache on archlinux 64bits

I've added it in my http.conf :

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess mart.localhost user=mart group=users processes=2 threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup mart.localhost
    LogLevel debug

    Alias /media /home/mart/programmation/python/django/martfiles/media/
    <Directory /home/mart/programmation/python/django/martfiles/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/http/wsgi-scripts/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to use the django.wsgi in my home folder but it doesn't work (`permission denied to access /`) (strangely it works if I use the test script given [here](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mod_wsgi#Test_mod_wsgi))

all the directories and content (apache folder, wsgi-script, martfiles) have the permission `775 root:devusers` with the group devusers including my user, http and root

in my template base.html, I call the css this way :

```
 <html>  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/style.css" />
```

and the error in /var/log/http/error.log

```
 [Sat Jan 16 13:22:21 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /media/css/style.css denied, referer: http://localhost/
 [Sat Jan 16 13:22:21 2010] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14783): Attach interpreter ''
```

[/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/166263/)

[/srv/http/wsgi-script/django.wsgi](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/165992)

[/home/.../martfiles/settings.py](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/165993/)

thank you

---

**edit** : I precise that my django website is working fine (except the sessions but I don't think it's related) so I'm not sure it's related to the django.wsgi file (maybe I'm wrong) but what is sure is that I should be able to use the django.wsgi from outside the apache folder

if I change the line `Alias /media /home/mart/programmation/python/django/martfiles/media/` with `Alias /media /srv/http/media/` and gives the right permissions, it works. But I don't want (and shouldn't) to put all my media in the apache folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not sufficient for just the directory '/home/mart/programmation/python/django/martfiles/media' containing static files to be readable and searchable. The user that Apache runs as must have read and potentially search access, to all parent directories of it back up to root directory. Since home directories on many systems are 'rwx------' this would deny Apache access irrespective of the Deny/Allow directives in Apache configuration.

Suggest you place the Django project and static files outside of your home account somewhere and relax the file system permissions as necessary.

Comment: that's why I gave the 775 permission with the group devusers containing my apache user (http). Where and which permission ? I'll try it

Comment: I put my medias in /usr/share/django with just root privileges and it works ! Thanks a lot

Comment: +1 for fixing my error.  What are the security implications of setting home permissions to 755?

Answer (score 3):

Your `django.wsgi` file,

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/http/wsgi-scripts/django.wsgi
```

is outside of the `<Directory>` defined by:

```
<Directory /home/mart/programmation/python/django/martfiles/>
```

Try adding this to `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory /srv/http/wsgi-scripts/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Or, put your `django.wsgi` file somewhere inside `/home/mart/programmation/python/django/martfiles/`. That should work.

EDIT: alright, here's an example httpd.conf that is working on a production machine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
    ServerAdmin testing@example.de
    ServerName  www.example.de

    DocumentRoot /home/example/testing/parts/public

    Alias /media /home/example/testing/parts/public/media

    # WSGI Settings
    WSGIDaemonProcess example user=example group=example threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/example/testing/parts/public/django.wsgi

    <Directory "/home/example/testing/parts/public">
        # Allow Apache to follow links
        Options FollowSymLinks
        # Turn on the ability to use .htaccess files
        AllowOverride All
        # Controls who can get stuff from this directory
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, if your dhango.wsgi is defined in a place set as accessible by a `<Directory>` directive, you could also `sudo su httpd` if that's the user that runs apache on your system, and simply try to read the css files, to see if apache can really access them...

Comment: if I put the django.wsgi in martfiles, I've an error 403 access denied ([error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied). if I add the <Directory /srv... it doesn't change anything ([error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /media/css/style.css denied, referer: http://localhost/).

Comment: Try simply adding `DocumentRoot /home/mart/programmation/python/django/martfiles` inside the `<VirtualHost>` section.

Comment: Where to put .htaccess file?

Comment: @sharafjaffri my example is a full apache config, not a `.htaccess` file. You put individual `.htaccess` files in each directory that you want to configure with them (the served directories).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what I have for my application except that I didn't see the `NameVirtualHost` directive in the http.conf which is required if you want to setup virtual servers. You can try adding `NameVirtualHost *:80` before the virtual host definition.

Comment: if I do that I've got one more error in the error.log : '[error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results'

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `NameVirtualHost *:80`. Updated the answer.