# Authentication in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to do connect form on my django website

If in a shell I do :

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Oct 27 2009, 06:25:13) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib import auth
>>> user = auth.authenticate(username='user', password='password')
>>>
```

no problem as you can see

but if on my views, I have :

```
# views.py
...
from django.contrib import auth
...

def check_pass(request):
    ...
    user = auth.authenticate(username='user', password='password')
    ...
```

I've got an 500 error page with the stacktrace :

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost/check_pass/
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mart/programmation/python/django/martfiles/views.py" in check_pass
  67.         user = auth.authenticate(username='user', password='password')
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  37.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  18.             user = User.objects.get(username=username)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  120.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  300.         num = len(clone)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  81.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  238.         for row in self.query.results_iter():
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in results_iter
  287.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in execute_sql
  2369.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  19.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  193.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /check_pass/
Exception Value: no such table: auth_user
```

my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
)
```

I've run 'syncdb' without any changes and I'm sure it's this line the problem as I isolated it with

```
assert False
user = auth...
```

AssertionError

```
user = auth...
assert False
```

no such table auth_user

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the same database from `manage.py shell` as you are when you hit your views? What happens if you hit the view code from the shell?

Comment: Yes maybe it's not the same (it would explain) but how can I check ? What do you mean by "hit the view code" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as for the [static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078160/static-file-with-modwsgi-in-django), I needed to put my database outside my home folder and not next to my python files.

Answer (score 1):

In the top of your script:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
```

Authentification:

```
 user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                #user is loged in
            else:
                # user is not active
        else:
            # false authentification
```

Comment: and you don't have anything else imported ? Can you show me your settings.py (maybe) ? I've tried with this very simple view (http://paste.pocoo.org/show/166380/) and still the error 'no such table: auth_user'