# How to include css stylesheet to Mako template

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, mako

I am using Mako templae engine for python. I want to add css stylesheet in my document, but I have no idea how to do that. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Make sure href points to your CSS file (and in the correct directory)

Taken straight from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp). There is nothing special about Mako templates, they just help you build up dynamic html.

Comment: No... it doesn't work, because I'am using mod_wsgi. Any other tip?

Comment: That is a different question, but you need to then configure Apache to serve static assets (in addition to the above) as far as I know (I don't use Python or Apache). See for a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078160/static-file-with-mod-wsgi-in-django

Answer (score 0):

[Mako docs for include](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#include)

```
<%include file="some_css_you_want_to_include.css" />
```

Comment: mako.exceptions.TemplateLookupException: Template 'template.txt' has no TemplateLookup associated